# Is it possible to have different settings from Windows settings in one place?

Tags: windows, windows-11

For example, I often need to tweak the brightness of SDR content (in HDR settings), sometimes I need to change the night color filter intensity, etc. Plenty of stuff that is usually in different places and it's not very convenient to go into each setting every time (especially for these 2 things because HDR or night mode settings are not even easily accessible and require going into submenus). Is it possible to have the settings (I mean toggles and sliders) I need in one place?

Comment: Is it possible to have the settings (I mean toggles and sliders) I need in one place?   ....  The setting is system wide, so what you want is most likely not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot customize the page layouts in the windows Settings app (other than hiding/disabling items), but you *can* use direct shortcuts to specific pages you use more often.

For example, the night color filter can be opened with `ms-settings:nightlight`. Copy that into a desktop shortcut or browser bookmark to make it a bit easier to find.

[image: screenshot]

There doesn't seem to be a direct link to the HDR settings page yet, but `ms-settings:display` gets you pretty close